# push命令(pushl)で invalid instruction suffix for push というエラーになる

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, gcc

下記のアセンブリの`pushl`の部分で`invalid instruction suffix for push`
というエラーが発生します

なぜ、`pushl`を使うとこのエラーが発生するのでしょうか?

環境
- gcc: 5.4.0
- os: ubuntu 16.04.2 x86_64

実行するアセンブリのコード  (参考 http://blog.livedoor.jp/hiroumauma/archives/1394375.html) :

```
.set EXIT, 1
.set READ, 3
.set WRITE, 4

.data
PROMPT: .string "input string >> "

.bss
var: .skip 16, 0x00

.text
.global main

main:
    pushl $PROMPT
    call print

    call scan

    pushl $var
    call print

    call exit

print:
    movl 4(%esp) ,%ecx
    movl $1, %ebx         # 標準出力へ
    movl $1, %edx         # 1文字出力
write:
    cmpb $0x00, (%ecx) # null文字かどうか
    je write_end
    movl $WRITE, %eax # write
    int $0x80
    incl %ecx                 # 次の文字
    jmp write
write_end:
    ret

scan:
    movl $READ, %eax  # readシステムコール
    xorl %ebx, %ebx     # 標準入力から
    movl $var, %ecx      # バッファを指定
    movl $16, %edx      # 16バイト読み込み
    int $0x80
    ret

exit:
    movl $EXIT, %eax    # exit
    movl $0, %ebx         # 終了コード0
    int $0x80
    # プログラムが終了するので、ret命令は省略
```

Comment: 64bit CPU/OS 環境の場合は `pushq` を使うのではないでしょうか。また、レジスタオペランドも `%esp` -> `%rsp` などに変更する必要があるかと思います(上記のコードを 32bit 環境でコンパイルする場合はエラーにはなりません)。

Comment: @metropolis  64bitの環境上で32bitのアセンブリを実行することはできないのでしょうか?
というのも元々xv6というx86向けに書かれたOSのコードを読むためにアセンブラの勉強をしているので、32bitでアセンブリを実行してみたいのです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848936/4315484)にあるように`gcc-multilib`パッケージをインストールし、`gcc -m32`でコンパイルすることで32bitバイナリを生成できます。